# Is it possible to present GADInterstitial on a full-screen UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial, gadinterstitial

I wonder if there's a way to present a GADInterstitial over a full-screen UICollectionViewCell. I've looked up for GADInterstitial delegate methods and the `interstitial.present(fromRootViewController:)` is the only method to display it, but in case of collection view cell the ad will be left under it, as it needs a rootViewController to be displayed on. So how's that can be reached?

Comment: you can make the UIViewController a delegate of the cell that has to present the add, and pass the delegate as a rootViewController

UIViewcontroller here is the controller in which your collectionView is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by using a Container View.

> Container View: Defines a region of a view controller that can include
>   a Child View Controller

So you can add a Container View to the `UICollectionViewCell`.

Worth mentioning is that depending on the implementation you may be violating the rules on how Interstitial ads can be used.